# How to declare xml namespace in JavaScript + Marklogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have xml documents like -

```
<domain xmlns:c="http://example.com/ns/core" xmlns="http://example.com/ns/core">
  <c:id>http://example.com/xyz/no-data</c:id>
</domain>
```

I am using JavaScript in MarkLogic, and want to run an [element value query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementValueQuery) on `c:id`. Something like this -

```
cts.elementValueQuery(xs.QName("c:id"), "http://example.com/xyz/no-data")
```

But for this I need to declare the namespace `c`. Has it been xQuery we could have done something like this -

```
declare namespace c="http://example.com/ns/core";
```

But I am not able to get how to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fn.QName()](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn.QName) instead of xs.QName(). In the example below, I've declared `nsC` (namespace-C) as something analogous to a declared namespace prefix.

```
const nsC = "http://example.com/ns/core";
cts.elementValueQuery(
  fn.QName(nsC, "id"), 
  "http://example.com/xyz/no-data"
)
```